# Trouble with splitting an array into chunks

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array:

```
private static int[] array = {5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 7, 8, 4};
```

I'm trying to split it into a two-dimensional array with x amount of chunks, where all of the chunks have an equal length (in my case, 2), then assign each value of the original array to a corresponding index within the array. It would then increment the index of the chunk number and reset the index iterating through the individual arrays hit the length of one.

Problem is, the code I wrote to perform all that isn't outputting anything:

```
public class Debug 
{
     private static int[] array = {5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 7, 8, 4};

     private static void chunkArray(int chunkSize) 
     {
         int chunkNumIndex = 0;
         int chunkIndex = 0;
         int numOfChunks = (int)Math.ceil((double)array.length / chunkSize);
         int[][] twoDimensionalArray = new int[numOfChunks][chunkSize];

         for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
         {
             twoDimensionalArray[chunkNumIndex][chunkIndex] = array[i];
             chunkIndex++;

             while(chunkNumIndex < numOfChunks)
             {
                 if (chunkIndex == chunkSize)
                 {
                     chunkNumIndex++;
                     chunkIndex = 0;
                 }
             }
         }

         for(int i = 0; i < chunkNumIndex; i++)
         {
             for(int j = 0; j < chunkIndex; j++)
             {
                 System.out.printf("%5d ", twoDimensionalArray[i][j]);
             }

             System.out.println();
         }
     }

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         chunkArray(2);
     }
  }
```

Could anyone be of assistance in debugging my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an unnecessary `while(chunkNumIndex < numOfChunks)` which makes no sense. The if statement is sufficient to iterate your variables correctly:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        twoDimensionalArray[chunkNumIndex][chunkIndex] = array[i];
        chunkIndex++;
        if (chunkIndex == chunkSize) {
            chunkNumIndex++;
            chunkIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Also, remember that the values of `chunkNumIndex` and `chunkIndex` are dynamic, so for the last for loops, use `twoDimensionalArray.length` and `twoDimensionalArray[0].length` instead:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < twoDimensionalArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <  twoDimensionalArray[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d ", twoDimensionalArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this unnecessarily hard, there is no need to keep counters for chunkIndex and chunkNumIndex, we can just div and mod i.

```
int numOfChunks = (array.length / chunkSize) + (array.length % chunkSize == 0 ? 0 : 1);
int[][] twoDimensionalArray = new int[numOfChunks][chunkSize];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    twoDimensionalArray[i / chunkSize][i % chunkSize] = array[i];
}
```

Something like this should already do the job.